# Powershell alternative to Unix who command to show ssh sessions

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

I am on a windows server and want to know who has ssh-ed into the server. On Linux following command works

```
who -s
```

What is its alternative on Windows 10?

Comment: Not exaclty equivalent but you cna run `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 22`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an elevated PowerShell, you can list all logged on users with:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogonSession | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LoggedOnUser
```

To only get the users that are logged on via SSH, you can use the following pipeline:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'sshd.exe'" | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_SessionProcess | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LoggedOnUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne 'SYSTEM'}
```

**Explanation:**

You are looking for accounts that are logged on (via SSH). In WMI, accounts are represented by the [`Win32_Account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-account) class. Logon sessions are represented by the [`Win32_LogonSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logonsession) class. If a user is logged on, a `Win32_Account` will be associated with a `Win32_LogonSession`. This association will be represented by an instance of the [`Win32_LoggedOnUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-loggedonuser) class.

The first pipeline from above takes all existing logon sessions and returns all user accounts that are associated with these logon sessions. In conclusion, you get a list of all logged on users.

To get a list of all users that are logged on via SSH, you can evaluate some more associations. Each process ([`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process)) is associated with a logon session via the [`Win32_SessionProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-sessionprocess) class. The second pipeline from above does the following:

1. It filters all processes to only get the processes of the SSH daemon.
2. For the SSH processes, it determines the associated logon sessions (`Win32_LogonSession`) via the `Win32_SessionProcess` association class.
3. It then uses these logon sessions to determine the logged on users via the `Win32_LoggedOnUser` association class like in the first pipeline.
4. In the end, it filters the result to omit the `SYSTEM` account.

Comment: Elegant solution, more informations returned than mine. You can even replace the `Where-Object ...` by filtering with the System Well Known Identity : `Where-Object {$_.SID -ne 'S-1-5-18'}` to get rid of international versions, useful if as part of a script.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the owner of the sshd process :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'sshd.exe'" | `
    Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName GetOwner | Where User -ne System
```

Then discard the System User which is used by the service itself, other users are the connected ones