# Windows Command To Check If Enable Screen Saver Policy Is Enabled

Tags: windows, powershell, command, group-policy

Can the **User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization\Enable screen saver** group policy setting be checked via command line? I am trying to see if it is set to enabled and if there is no user session, to output something like no user-session available.

Comment: There is an official documentation out there (an excel sheet from MS) that translates GP settings to registry settings. Look for the corresponding registry setting and then you can query it with reg.exe or the `Get-ItemProperty` cmdlet via console.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/101451

Comment: Hi @stackprotector, thank you for the feedback, I have found the registry value for that group policy setting. HKEY_USERS\\S-1-5-21-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]{3,}\\[Ss][Oo][Ff][Tt][Ww][Aa][Rr][Ee]\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Control Panel\\Desktop\\ScreenSaveActive, the only problem now is that this key only exists when users are logged in, is there a way to query this for the users and if the user is not logged in, to echo something like, "there is no user session"?

Comment: You can use WMI to query all users that are currently logged in. Then take their SIDs and check the paths in the registry.

Comment: Hi @stackprotector, I am struggling to craft the code for this, any chance you can help me with this?

Comment: From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66851552/11942268), you can derive how to query all logged on users.

Comment: Besides that, SO is not a coding service. Obviously, your question is very broad. I recommed to divide your problem into smaller problems. Solve them one by one. If you still cannot get it to work, post another question with a more atomic problem.